# Decode caracteres do email

Tags: php, email, dom, codificação-de-caracteres

Estou tentando importar dados de um email e consigo pegar os dados, porém alguns caracteres vem em um encoding que eu não achei como converter, como por exemplo.

```
Goioer=C3=AA
Paran=C3=A1
```

Tentei utf8_decode, quoted_printable_decode e outras funções.
Se alguém puder ajudar.

Answer (score 2):

Quando esses caracteres vêm nos cabeçalhos, a codificação não é bem quoted-printable, mas sim q-encoding. São codificações parecidas, mas são diferentes, pelo que não tem uma função específica no PHP para decodificar q-encoding.

Para decodificação de email eu uso a classe [MIME E-mail Parser](http://www.phpclasses.org/package/3169-PHP-Decode-MIME-e-mail-messages.html) que decodifica todo tipo de mensagens sem ter de ficar estudando os documentos RFCs que definem os padrões de email.